# Php codeigniter login form

Tags: php

I have registered users already and they have a username and password but i want them to be able to login.
I want the user to be directed to another page(home) if login successfully.
public function login()//controller
    {

```
$username = $_POST['user_login'];
$password = $_POST['user_password'];
$query = $this->general_model->get_by(array('username'  =>"$username", 'password' => "$password"), NULL, TRUE);
if($query->num_rows == 1)
{
$row = $query->row();
$data = array(
             // 'staff_id' => $row->staff_id,
              'username' => $row->username,
              'password' => $row->password
              );
//$this->session->set_userdata('username', $_POST['username']);
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
return true;
}
}
```

my view login form

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<body>
<?php //echo validatoin_errors(); ?>
<?php  echo form_open('school_settings'); ?>
 <div class="m-content">
 <div style="opacity: 1; transform: scale(1); transition: all   0.5s ease   0s;" class="login-form padding20 block-shadow">
    <form method="get" action="">
        <h1 class="text-light">Login </h1>
        <hr class="thin">
        <br>
        <div class="input-control text" data-role="input">
            <label for="user_login">Username:</label>
            <input style="padding-right: 39px;" name="username"     id="user_login" type="text">
            <button type="button" tabindex="-1" class="button   helper-button clear"><span class="mif-cross"></span></button>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="input-control password" data-role="input">
            <label for="user_password">User password:</label>
            <input style="padding-right: 39px;" name="password"     id="user_password" type="password">
            <button type="button" tabindex="-1" class="button   helper-button reveal"><span class="mif-looks"></span></button>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" class="button primary">Login  to...</button>
            <button type="button" class="button link">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please note that SO is not a coding service, maybe you should read ["How to ask"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Include what you already tried and try to run down your issue to a specific problem.

Comment: num_rows is a function num_rows()